# Acessar colunas de tabela relacionada por meio do ORM DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Como ter acesso ao objeto `user` e seus atributos após um `join`?

Essa é minha consulta

```
Idea.objects.select_related("user").values("author_id").annotate(
        qtd=Count('author_id'))
```

Exemplo de um resultado:

```
<QuerySet [{'author_id': 1, 'qtd': 6}, {'author_id': 2, 'qtd': 8}]>
```

Com esse resultado, eu consigo acessar os valores `author_id` e `qtd` no meu template:

```
 {% for d in ideas %}
    {{d.qtd}} - {{d.author_id}}
 {% endfor %}
```

Porém, eu precisaria ter acesso a todas as colunas da minha tabela `user` para que eu possa acessar os campos do sistema de admin do django: `username`, `email` etc..

Meu modelo:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    use_term_accept = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    manager = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Idea(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('data criação')
    author = models.ForeignKey('users.UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='old_author')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('users.UserProfile', related_name='authors')
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Espero ter sido claro, qualque duvida vou respondedo.

Obg

Comment: Oi mr.abdo, não entendi bem, a tabela user que você cita é a gerada pela classe UserProfile? Nenhum dos dois models tem os valores username e email. Ou você quer acessar os dados dos usuários cadastrados pelo próprio sistema de administração do Django?

Comment: @GiovaneMachado quero acessar os dados do sistema de administraçaõ do Django. Editei a questão p deixar claro.

Comment: @GiovaneMachado, esqueci de responder a outra pergunta. User é gerada por UserProfile.

Comment: Certo. Estou verificando na documentação, e acredito fortemente que você pode sim retornar o email e username de quem está logado no momento. Provavelmente basta usar: variavel = User.objects.get(username). E para o email o mesmo, logo elaborarei melhor.

Comment: O problema é q preciso retornar o email dentro da queryset para que eu possa iterá-la no template.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver esse problema. Vou registrar aqui para ajudar alguém caso passe pelo mesmo.

Passei a chave `author__user__email` para o resultado colocando `author__user__email` em values.

```
Idea.objects.values("author_id", "author__user__email").annotate(
    total=Count('author_id'))
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444812/how-can-i-access-the-object-user-django-admin-using-group-by-and-join

Answer (score 1):

Samyr,
Voce ja tentou acessar o objeto? Apesar dessa visualizacao que o Django te da do queryset o seu objeto inteiro estara la:

```
>>> p = Product.objects.select_related('category').last()
>>> p.category
>>> <Category: teste>
```